# What is the origin of the word "tascalate"?

Tags: etimología, palabras-raras, méxico, comida

Another unusual Spanish word I collected in my travels is `tascalate`.

It's a drink in Chiapas, Mexico and there are Wikipedia articles about it [in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tascalate) and [in Spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tascalate).

But it's not in Wiktionary or the DRAE and the Wikipedia article doesn't say where the word comes from. It looks like it could well be derived from normal Spanish morphemes but that doesn't rule out the possibility that it derived from a native language of Mexico.

**Does anybody know the etymology of "tascalate"?**

Comment: Taking into account that this is a Mexican drink, I would venture to say that it's a compound name in which the last part *late* comes from the Náhuatl word * ā-tl* (agua), as is the case with *xocoatl* (*chocolate*). Of course, this is only a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this page](http://www.amunmaya.com/?page_id=11) there's a theory about the origin of *tazcalate* (with "z"):

> (...) este nombre deriva de la palabra “Tlaxcalli” en Náhuatl que significa Tortilla.

Comment: > El orígen de la palabra “Tazcalate” es todo un enigma.